# WPF: How do I inherit property values to all child controls?

Tags: wpf, user-interface, xaml, properties, foreground

I have UserControls containing other controls. I want that if I set a Foreground color for the UserControl, all child controls automatically inherit it. I have the same problem with font style/size.

Can I set these properties somehow to auto/inherit? Is this possible to set all subcontrols without a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can you create resource dictionaries to define default styles globally.

You can also reference a resource dictionary or define a style in any object.

In either case those styles will apply to all child objects that don't have a style explicitly defined...

Example:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >
    <!--Default styles that will apply to any object of the specified type (if it doesn't have style set locally)-->
    <Style TargetType="Label" >
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into using Styles and BasedOn settings.

I recently wrote an example of something similar located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262915/wpf-xaml-set-a-style-with-a-different-targettype/1263178#1263178).  Unfortunally the question was related to Silver Lite so didn't answer the question, but I think it may give you some ideas on where to look.